# Saving doc files as word templates

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I want to open .doc files and save them in .dotx word templates format. How can I do that using x++ ?
any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is something ideally suited for a helper assembly using .NET Interop. This is an abstract question so the answer is pretty abstract, but basically program what you want in a C# class, then access that C# class from AX.

This link has all sorts of sub-links that are excellent resources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/net-interop-from-x

Just google how to convert `.doc` to `.dotx` with C# (or whatever language) and that's what you would connect to AX. Here's the first google result I found: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/547a13dc-6c9c-47bf-859a-312965e952ec/how-to-convert-a-dotx-into-docx-file-with-c-and-open-xml?forum=innovateonoffice